# Liquibase puts wrong baseTableSchemaName into addForeignKeyConstraint

Tags: mysql, liquibase

I have two databases with same username and password and I want to generate SQL instructions to upgrade first database (skryb) to second (skryb1):

```
call liquibase --driver=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver ^
      --classpath=../lib/mysql-connector-java-5.1.20-bin.jar ^
      --url="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/skryb" ^
      --username=skryb ^
      --password=skryb ^
      --referenceUrl="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/skryb1" ^
      --referenceUsername=skryb ^
      --referencePassword=skryb ^
      --changeLogFile=1.xml ^
      diffChangeLog 


call liquibase --driver=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver ^
      --classpath=../lib/mysql-connector-java-5.1.20-bin.jar ^
      --url="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/skryb" ^
      --username=skryb ^
      --password=skryb ^
      --changeLogFile=1.xml ^
      updateSQL > 1.sql
```

Inside 1.xml there is a generated xml tag:

```
<changeSet author="steve (generated)" id="1357484117018-4">
    <addForeignKeyConstraint baseColumnNames="messageDetails_id" baseTableName="messageline" baseTableSchemaName="skryb1" constraintName="FK2F5B707BF7C835B8" deferrable="false" initiallyDeferred="false" onDelete="NO ACTION" onUpdate="NO ACTION" referencedColumnNames="id" referencedTableName="messagedetails" referencedTableSchemaName="skryb1" referencesUniqueColumn="false"/>
</changeSet>
```

why baseTableSchemaName & referencedTableSchemaName are the same here? Generated SQL is also wrong:

```
ALTER TABLE `skryb1`.`messageline` ADD CONSTRAINT `FK2F5B707BF7C835B8` FOREIGN KEY (`messageDetails_id`) REFERENCES `skryb1`.`messagedetails` (`id`) ON UPDATE NO ACTION ON DELETE NO ACTION;
```

(i don't want to update skryb1, I want to update skryb. And the rest of sql instructions don't reference skryb1.)